# Error "...function for 'xxx' did not return a valid response"

Tags: python, flask

Consider:

```
def xxx():
    .....
    if request.method == 'POST':
        _form = request.form.to_dict()
        if 'btn_save' in _form:
            try:
                session.flush()
                ...
                session.add(new_1)
                ...
                session.add(new_2)
                ...
                session.add(new_3)
                session.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('xxx.xxx'))
            except Exception:
                session.rollback()
                raise
                return app_api.render_page(mod.name + "/xxx.html", **context_cement)

        context = {
            'heading': heading,
        }
        return app_api.render_page(mod.name + "/xxx.html", **context)
```

I get an error:

> raise TypeError(.... TypeError: The view function for 'xxx' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, are you making a POST request? Or some other HTTP method?

Comment: python is based on indentation, so you are basically return inside the POST condition, please consider a return outside the first if condition

Comment: if you only want to handle HTTP POST on that endpoint, then change its decorator to `@app.post("/xxx")`

Comment: For some reason, this question has an [extremely high view rate](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120902/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4) (nearly 10,000 on average per day). It is currently #1 on the entire Stack Overflow (out of all [23,691,708 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)), but it will of course fall as it gets older. (In [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info), it is sampled *once per week*, thus the discrepancy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is that this function is returning None. Why is that? Because you are returning a Response *only* on `POST` requests (you didn't provide the other parts of your function's code so check them yourself if there are other situations in which you have not returned a Response).

Make sure you return a valid Response object no matter what happens in the view function.

To see which blocks of code are executed, try to debug the program or simply place some print statements in different `if` statements. But the error is exactly saying that in your situation the function didn't reach a return statement to return an appropriate Response object. Also, I suggest printing the `request.method` to see in which cases the response is None.